# how to exclude only those TR which having nested SPAN with a class?

Tags: jquery

I have a table like below, couple of TD having SPAN with class "exclude"

```
<table class="abc">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <span class="exclude"></span>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need to exclude all those TR which having nested SPAN with class "exclude"?

How to do this, I tried below, but not working,

```
tr:not(.exclude)
```

Comment: that is invalid markup.....;) only `td` can be the child of `tr` and then you can put anything in the `td`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am assuming your html is valid as you have stated `couple of TD having SPAN with class "exclude`. which makes your html to:

```
<table class="abc">
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td><span class="exclude"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thus, You can use `:not` with `:has` selector :

```
$('tr:not(:has(.exclude))');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wveqqcz3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Your html is invalid, you need to put the span in a td element.

Then in jQuery you can use the .not() and :has() filters

```js
$('tr').not(':has(.exclude)').css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="abc">
  <tr>
    <td>1<span class="exclude"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$('tr').not(".exclude")
```

After you've put the span in a td element like a normal person

Comment: _put the span in a td element like a normal person_ hahaha very interesting still you have a wrong selector. oops!!!